# Building opencv with mingw. Fails when I import cv2. DLL load failed. Looking for .dll, but I have .dll.a's

Tags: python, opencv, mingw

I'm trying to build OpenCV with MSYS / MinGW so I can use the cv2 module in python. 
I'm on Windows 7 64-bit and using 32 bit Python 2.7. Building OpenCV works, but I cannot seem to use it without getting an "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." after importing cv2. I've been debugging it for awhile, and the common google solutions seem not to work.

These are the steps I have taken:

- Removed all other instance of opencv from my computer (there were a few)
- Built opencv with CMake and I manually set these flags:

  ```
           'CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX'       : 'C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenCV'
           'CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE'           : 'Release',
           'CMAKE_C_FLAGS'              : '-m32',
           'CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS'            : '-m32',
           'BUILD_opencv_gpu'           : False,
           'BUILD_opencv_gpuarithm'     : False,
           'BUILD_opencv_gpubgsegm'     : False,
           'BUILD_opencv_gpucodec'      : False,
           'BUILD_opencv_gpufeatures2d' : False,
           'BUILD_opencv_gpufilters'    : False,
           'BUILD_opencv_gpuimgproc'    : False,
           'BUILD_opencv_gpuoptflow'    : False,
           'BUILD_opencv_gpustereo'     : False,
           'BUILD_opencv_gpuwarping'    : False
  ```
- I do a cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..., make -j9, and finally a make install. The printouts show that the libraries go where I expect them to.
- My PATH includes

  ```
           C:\MinGW\bin
           C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
           C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2
           C:\Python27\
           C:\Python27\Scripts
           C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV
           C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV\lib
  ```
- My PYTHONPATH includes

  ```
           C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
           C:\Python27
  ```
- I then copy

  - cv2.pyd and libcv2.dll.a from C:\Python\Lib\site-packages
  - all libopencv_*249.dll.a from C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV\lib
  - libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll libstdc++-6.dll from C:\MinGW\bin
  - I MOVE ALL OF THESE into a directory I named cv2
- In the cv2 directory I made an __init__.py file containing the following code:

  ```
       import os, sys
       from os.path import realpath, dirname
       tpl_cv2 = realpath(dirname(__file__))
       print(tpl_cv2)
       sys.path.insert(0,tpl_cv2)
       os.environ['PATH'] = tpl_cv2 + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
       try:
           from cv2 import *
       except Exception as ex:                       
           print(repr(ex))
           print(os.environ['PATH'])
           print(sys.path)
           raise
  ```
- I then open a IPython terminal and enter the command "import cv2"

And I get the error: ImportError('DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.',)

---

To debug this I've:

- I load up the cv2.pyd file in depends.exe It shows that

LIBOPENCV_CALIB3D249.DLL and all the other opencv libs are not found. However, these are all in the same directory as cv2.pyd as well as in both the PATH and PYTHONPATH.

But they are named .dll.a because I compiled with MSYS / MinGW. I don't understand why its looking for the .dll without the .a suffix. I think this probably has something to do with the error, but I don't know where to go from here.

- I've also built a small C++ application which reads and image using the OpenCV that I've built. It builds just fine, but I get the error: The program can't start because libopencv_core249.dll is missing from your computer. So, I'm more convinced this .dll.a thing is the issue.
- I've tried simply renaming the libs from .dll.a to .dll, but that didn't work.

I'm hoping someone can shed light on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I feel really stupid. The dlls were in "C:\Program Files (x86)\bin" not "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib" It seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

This post helped me a lot.  The answer I found was to make sure the compiled bin files were part of my PATH variable.

My CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX was C:\opencv\src\build\install
and adding C:\opencv\src\build\install\x86\vc11\bin to my PATH variable made cv2 start working.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure other users can be helped with this answer:

Imagine you have compiled OpenCV and have several *.dll and the cv2.pyd file.

You need to copy those files to 'DLLs' folder within the python directory.

Then import the module to check wether it is ok.
I have also copied the *.lib files into the appropriate folder.

Best regards.